# Removing header from cached response with NGINX

Tags: python, caching, nginx, cookies, response-headers

I have NGINX running as a reverse proxy in front of a few Flask apps.

I want to implement caching for logged out users.

Flask-login adds a `Set-Cookie` header for every response, even for anonymous users, as it contains a session cookie with a CSRF token. This means that that I'm using `proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;` to ensure that stuff actually get's cached by NGINX (which won't cache and response with a `Set-Cookie` header).

I'm setting a separate cookie in the apps to indicate the logged in/out status of a user and using that to determine whether to use the cache or not. This works great.

The issue is that the cached responses for a logged out user include the `Set-Cookie` header which sets the session cookie. This session cookie is served to any request that hits the cache, which ultimately results in different users receiving the same CSRF token.

I would like to either prevent the `Set-Cookie` header being stored in the cache, or remove/overwrite it when it's sent to the client from the cache.

I've tried setting `proxy_hide_headers Set-Cookie` which removes it from cached responses, but also from responses from that app. So no one can log in. Which is bad.

It feels like there should be a really easy solution to this, I just can find it no matter how hard I google.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, not for Flask, just for a PHP site. I feel the solution will require some modification to the nginx files, or a complex condition inside location{}, like an if cache is a HIT hide header.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** After trying a million things I have a solution that’s working for multiple cookies, I would like your opinions.
On Debian 10 I installed `apt-get install libnginx-mod-http-lua` I think this is not the complete OpenResty lua-nginx-module, isn’t it?

```
map $upstream_bytes_received $hide_cookie {
   default '';
   '' Set-Cookie;
}
```

Inside location:

```
header_filter_by_lua_block {
   ngx.header[ngx.var.hide_cookie] = nil;
}
```

And it works, I will do more testing...

---

**Previous answer**, for 1 cookie, without Lua:

I've been working on a solution for this, but for now it works for **ONLY ONE** cookie.

First I faced the following problems:  `$proxy_hide_header` does not accept variables, and cannot be used inside `if()`.
I finally found an answer that contained a viable solution to that: [Using a Header to Filter Proxied Response Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53754229/using-a-header-to-filter-proxied-response-headers).

So this is my code for now , that I will test more, because is a delicate matter:

```
map $upstream_bytes_received $cookies {
default $upstream_http_set_cookie;
'' '';
}
```

And then inside location:

```
    proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
    add_header Set-Cookie $cookies;
```

Maybe I would make the default: No cookies, that will be noticeable if fails, and less problematic regarding privacy.

But this solution I think cannot be improved for multiple cookies, I have to look elsewhere, if I could force the use of variables at `$proxy_hide_header` would be the end solution.