# Using a Header to Filter Proxied Response Headers

Tags: http, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an upstream server that often sets Cookie(s) by returning the "Set-Cookie" response header.

I would like to have an nginx proxy in front of said upstream server:

```
Browser => Nginx => Upstream
```

If the `Browser => Nginx` request had the header `X-No-Cookies: true` I'd like the response from `Upstream => Nginx => Browser` not to contain the `Set-Cookie` response header. If `X-No-Cookies` had any other value, I'd lie the `Set-Cookie` response header to be returned unaltered. **I'm not able to change the response header behavior of the upstream server.**

Currently my nginx config is as follows, pay specific attention to the use of the `proxy_hide_header` directive. I've also echoed the `$proxy_hide_header` variable in the `X-No-Cookies` response header.

```
map $http_x_no_cookies $proxy_hide_header {
  default "";
  "true"  "Set-Cookie";
}

# Homepage
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location /api {
    proxy_pass        https://example.com/api;
    proxy_hide_header $proxy_hide_header;
    add_header        "X-No-Cookies" $proxy_hide_header;
  }
}
```

When I make a request with cURL:

```
curl \
  http://example.com/api \
  -H 'X-No-Cookies: true' \
  -I
```

I get the following response headers:

```
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 02:26:41 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 2255
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length
Set-Cookie: foo=bar; Max-Age=2592000; Expires=Sat, 12 Jan 2019 02:26:41 GMT; Path=/; Domain=example.com; Secure
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-No-Cookies: Set-Cookie
```

Whenever the `proxy_hide_header` is provided an nginx variable as an argument it seems to have no effect. If I swap the variable for a string (`$proxy_hide_header` substituted for `"Set-Cookie"`) I get the desired behaviour - the `Set-Cookie` response header is omitted.

**Edit**: I've pushed the code for this question to GitHub

- My original (non-working) implementation is [here](https://github.com/aren55555/nginx-dynamic-proxy_hide_header/blob/master/nginx/nginx.conff#L118)
- Ivan Shatsky's solution is [here](https://github.com/aren55555/nginx-dynamic-proxy_hide_header/blob/ivan-shatsky-solution/nginx/nginx.conf#L113)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What an interesting challenge! Truly, `$proxy_hide_header` does not accept variables as its parameter and cannot be used inside an `if` blocks. Also we cannot use `$upstream_...` variables directly inside a `location` block because its values are not evaluated yet. Finally I found a solution. We always hide `Set-Cookie` header and then set it again if needed, values calculating through `map` expressions:

```
map $http_x_no_cookies $hide_cookies {
    default "0";
    "true"  "1";
}

map $hide_cookies$upstream_http_set_cookie $cookies {
    ~^0(.*)$ $1;
}

upstream backend {
    server example.com;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass        https://backend/api;
        proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
        add_header Set-Cookie $cookies;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you know proxy_hide_header does not accept variables as its parameter? I was reading this doc (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header) and couldn't find that info.

Comment: I think this can be called an experience :) Unless the nginx documentation on some directive explicitly states that variables may be used as its parameters, usually it means that they cannot. This is nginx way of documenting directives.

Comment: @Ivan Do you think there is a solution for multiple cookies? this solution will only work for one cookie. I'm working on it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470330/removing-header-from-cached-response-with-nginx/59383747

Comment: @Vixxs Working with headers is tricky, I think if I faced such problem I would try to solve it with OpenResty. It is an nginx fork with embedded Lua scripting. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016867/how-come-i-cannot-set-multiple-cookies) question to see some examples.

Comment: @Ivan Hi I did it with a little bit of Lua in the same Nginx install, I'm a newbie at this, could you check my solution, do you think its solid?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470330/removing-header-from-cached-response-with-nginx/59383747#59383747