# nginx map of header from upstream goes to default

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I want to have a conditional header based on a header I want to get from the upstream.
For some reason it always gets translated to default.

Configuration:
upstream service decides if a header called x-no-iframe-protection should exist.

main nginx:

```
map $http_x_no_iframe_protection $x_frame_options {
    yes "";
    default "SAMEORIGIN";
}

server {
    ...
    add_header X-Frame-Options $x_frame_options;
    ...
}
```

No matter what I try - I get both headers:

```
$ curl -v myhost
...
< x-no-iframe-protection: yes
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
...
```

Just to clarify - I use the x-no-iframe-protection just as a trick to remove x-frame-options in specific cases. I'm OK with it staying (although it is not needed once parsed by nginx)

Anyways - how can I make it get caught in order to replace the header value?

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53754229/using-a-header-to-filter-proxied-response-headers), I think this question is similar to yours.

Comment: `$http_x_no_iframe_protection` is the value of a request header, you may have some luck with `$sent_http_x_no_iframe_protection` which is the value of the response header.

Comment: @RichardSmith - it worked! please formulate your comment as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An HTTP transaction contains request headers and response headers. From the context of your question you are setting the value of a response header based on the value of another **response** header (which was received from upstream).

Nginx stores request headers in variables with names beginning with `$http_` and response headers in variables with names beginning with `$sent_`.

In addition, response headers received from upstream may also be stored in variables with names beginning with `$upstream_http_`.

In your configuration you use the variable `$http_x_no_iframe_protection`, whereas you should be using either `$sent_x_no_iframe_protection` or perhaps `$upstream_http_x_no_iframe_protection`.

All of the Nginx variables are [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html).

Answer (score 0):

try using `$upstream_x_no_iframe_protection` to access upstream response header.